# How can i properly send a stream from forked child process in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, child-process, database-cursor, fastify

I tried something like this in the forked child process:

WriterPlugin.js (child process)

```
  function sendCursor(){
                        try {
                let cursor = await getQueryCursor(reqBody, db);
                cursor.on('data', (data) => {
                    process.send(data);
                })
            } catch (error) {
                process.send({
                    message: error.toString(),
                    status: 400
                })
            }
        }
```

controller.js  (parent process)

`const childProcess = fork(fileToExec);
    childProcess.send(objectToProcess);
    childProcess.on('message', (data) => {
            reply.send(data);
    })`

This one printed just last data of cursor and i faced with a fastifyError:

```
"code":"FST_ERR_REP_ALREADY_SENT","statusCode":500},"msg":"Reply already sent"}
```

How can i properly **handle** the **cursor.stream()** from a forked child process using fastify?

Comment: Are you facing any errors?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara I have tried in various ways but or i faced with "dest.on is not a function" or i was able to print just last record. Any idea?

Comment: You need to share little more code and error stack to help you out.

Comment: as @ApoorvaChikara suggested, i added some extra code and the stacktrace. I Hope this help

Comment: It is little difficult where the problem might be in the code , but error says that response already being sent, so check if you are sending response twice somewhere.

Comment: Yes i know, because i'm sending during stream for this i'm looking for alternative solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to push the data into a stream to accomplish this task:

```js
const { fork } = require('child_process')
const { Readable } = require('stream')

const fastify = require('fastify')()

fastify.get('/', (request, reply) => {
  const stream = new Readable({
    read (size) {}
  })

  const childProcess = fork('./external-file.js')
  childProcess.on('message', (data) => {
    stream.push(JSON.stringify(data)) // it must be a string
  })
  childProcess.on('close', (data) => {
    stream.push(null)
  })

  reply.send(stream)
})

fastify.listen(8080)
```

Where `external-file.js` is:

```js
let iteration = 0
const timer = setInterval(() => {
  const data = { iteration: iteration++ }
  process.send(data)

  if (iteration === 3) {
    clearInterval(timer)
  }
}, 1000)
```

Comment: This answer was a good starting point for properly handling the stream from the child process. I encountered a problem sending the promise from the child process because i was sending data through process.send() in cursor.on event, but the parent could not know when the son had finished, so reply.send started before the resolution of the stream and process.on. In externalFile.js i implemented cursor.on('close) to send process .exit and works fine.